# Animation sprite sheet

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate some characters for a school project but I am running into problems. As I am totally new to this world so I am looking for some guidance and I was hoping this would be the right place.

My first question:

I've made a sprite sheet in illustrator for one of my characters. http://gryfaberbay.dk/kea/forhelp/spritesheet.png (I've made it into a png file so you guys can see) When I try to animate my character and make her walk by using my sprite sheet the feet from the overlying sprite show.

Here's my code:

```
#princess_sprite {
background-image: url(img/spritesheet_prinsesse.svg);
width: 18vw;
height: 45vw;
background-size: 300%;
/* - mod venstre. */
}

.princess_walkcycle {
animation-name: princess_walkcycle_kf;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: steps(3);

}

@keyframes princess_walkcycle_kf {
0% {
    background-position: 0%;
}
100% {
    background-position: -300%;
}
}

#princess_container {
position: absolute;
top: 8%;
left: 50%;
}

.princess_move_left {
animation-name: princess_move_left_kf;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
/*animation-timing-function: ease;*/
}

@keyframes princess_move_left_kf {
0% {
    left: 100%;
}
100% {
    left: 71.31%;
}
}
```

I am hoping you guys are willing to help me! Thanks so much :)

Sincerely,
Gry

Comment: Can you provide working sample? If you see some other sprite part, that means your *view-box* is too big.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `height` and `width` of `#princess_sprite` in conjunction with `background-size` property.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```css
#princess_sprite {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://gryfaberbay.dk/kea/forhelp/spritesheet.png);
  background-size: 300%;
  animation-name: princess_walkcycle_kf;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(3);
}

@keyframes princess_walkcycle_kf {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="princess_sprite">
</div>
```